# How to save ImageSource to jpg in maui?

Tags: maui

i want to save ImageSource result from screen shoot in maui.
i found error in casting :

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Main:

```
using ScreenShot.ViewModel;
    namespace ScreenShot;
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly MainViewModel viewModel;
        public MainPage(MainViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;
        }   
    }
```

and xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ScreenShot.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel"
             x:Class="ScreenShot.MainPage">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />            
            <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Take screen shot" Command="{Binding TakeScreenShotCommand}" />            
            <Image Source="{Binding ScreenGrab}" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Service Class:

```
namespace ScreenShot
{
    public class AndroidService : MyService
    {
        public async void Convert(string filename, ImageSource img)
        {
            var handler = new FileImageSourceHandler();
            Bitmap pic = await handler.LoadImageAsync(img, Android.App.Application.Context);//here the error (Casting Error)

            var savedImageFilename = Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/CAMERA", filename);
            Stream outputStream;
            using (outputStream = new FileStream(savedImageFilename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                bool success;
                if (Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower() == ".png")
                {
                    success = await pic.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, outputStream);
                }
                else
                    success = await pic.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, outputStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace ScreenShot.ViewModel;

public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly MyService myService;
    
    public MainViewModel(MyService myService)
    {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    ImageSource _screenGrab;

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task TakeScreenShot()
    {        
        ScreenGrab = await TakeScreenshotAsync();
        myService.Convert("abcd", ScreenGrab);
    }
        
    private async Task<ImageSource> TakeScreenshotAsync()
    {
        if (Screenshot.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
        {
            IScreenshotResult screen = await Screenshot.Default.CaptureAsync();

            Stream stream = await screen.OpenReadAsync();

            return ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
        }
        return null;
    }    
}
```

Interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ScreenShot
{
    public interface MyService
    {
        public void Convert(string filename, ImageSource img);
    }
}
```

Services builder:

```
using ScreenShot.ViewModel;

namespace ScreenShot;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyService, AndroidService>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

the error result in Service Class file mention above due to ivalid casting
is there a way to solve problem?

Comment: Your service is creating a file before you create the ImageSource.  You don’t need to create another one

Comment: no, ImageSource create image first, then i use service to convert ImageSource to jpg file to save it.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason suggested, you don't need create another one as the method `Task<ImageSource> TakeScreenshotAsync()` captures a screenshot and returns it as an ImageSource, you can directly use it as an Image source. So the easiest way is to remove the code below in your viewmodel, it should display the `captured screenshot`.

```
 myService.Convert("abcd", ScreenGrab);
```